# FreeBSD11: Hanging from time to time

Tags: freebsd

I’m running FreeBSD on my beaglebone black headless server and everything looks perfect, however, after some time idle (no user interaction) it stops responding to any incoming connection (ssh/http) but if I ping it, I get an answer back.

It was not accepting ssh or http connections, I’ve used an app called **Fing** to ping the BBB and it responded the pings but nothing else was responding. I tried the Wake on LAN function and it started to respond ssh and http. Coincidence or not, I was experiencing these “hangs” everyday, several times a day, after the WoL the BBB is up and running for 3 days now. I didn’t restart the BBB. I had a look on dmesg to see if there is any apm running and nothing, /var/log/messages doesn’t give me any clue, looks like nothing happened. The BBB is wired straight to my router and the IP address is locked/reserved to its MAC address.

Tried to check **apm** status but **apm** is not installed.

[image]

Also tried to install **apm** but no success.

[image]

Tried to check if there is any kernel module loaded (**kldstat**) to manage power, but it doesn’t look like the case:

[image: kldstat]

Did anyone face a similar issue, or know if there is any way to prevent FreeBSD to “sleep”, or have a clue of what is happening?

Comment: What does `apm -s` says?

Comment: apm: command not found

Comment: Append `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` to your `PATH`, and [edit] the _then_ answer to M. Ribeiro's query into your question.

Comment: A wild guess: your NIC enters a power saving state.  This problem comes up every once in a while across different machines and OSes.

Comment: @JdeBP my path already has these folders. Happens that there is no “apm” available

Comment: @SatōKatsura I’ve been running Debian on BBB and never experienced any sort of “sleep” mode. It has been up for 2 days now but I’m not sure if and when it will hang again.

Comment: So maybe the problem was fixed for Linux, for that particular NIC?

Comment: Also tried to check if there is any apm module loaded by the kernel but doesn’t look like it is.

Comment: You might want to try if this is happening as well with FreeBSD Current/Stable. Also do you use zfs on the BBB?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens I’m using the version 11 RELEASE installed to a microSD stock from the image downloaded from FreeBSD.org. I was surprised to see the zfs module as well, but my file systems are stock ufs.

Comment: When you say it “comes back to life” after using WoL, does it boot, or does it immediately start accepting SSH connections again?  I guess there is nothing relevant in the messages log?

Comment: @forquare It was not accepting ssh or http connections, I’ve used Fing to ping the BBB and it responded but nothing else was responding. I tried the WoL function and it started to respond ssh and http. Coincidence or not, I was experiencing these “hangs” everyday, several times a day, after the WoL the BBB is up and running for 3 days now. I didn’t restart the BBB. I had a look on dmesg to see if there is any apm running and nothing, /var/log/messages doesn’t give me any clue, looks like nothing happened. The BBB is wired straight to my router.

Comment: If there's no `apm` available then something is wrong.  `/usr/sbin/apm` is part of base in 11 RELEASE, and it is in the CD install image.

Comment: @JdeBP I understand, but I used the image for Beaglebone Black maintained by FreeBSD.org. Unless if I’ve mistakenly removed this package, it was not part of the original image. I will install it.

Comment: @JdeBP found that apm is superseded by ACPI and is only supported on i386/amd64. The BBB is arm, so it may explain why apm/ACPI are not present.